# c# email link ampersand is replaced by pilcrow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, symbols

I'm trying to send a confirmation link but I don't know why my symbol is replaced by nonsense. The "&" is changed to "¶m".

I already tried a lot of things and nothing works for C# MVC controller.

I already use this code in a lot of projects and I never had this strange bug.

Source code : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWmuW.png]

Result (the issue) [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/na9aJ.png]

Comment: What is the text surrounding the '&'? How is it used?

Comment: I really like the way you post images to show your code.

Comment: It for the debug mode, it show me when the mail is sent the link is correctly formatted, but when i try to click on it in outlook the link is formatted with other char.

Comment: text arround is :
exemple:
?paramID=10&Token=PDAPDSADASDASD

Comment: Likely garbage-in-garbage-out... Please consider showing code as text so it is readable... And make sure to show how HTML in paramMessage is created. I suspect caller of the method is the one who is at fault as valid HTML is expected there and likely it passed sh* as you said in the post. Blame the caller - no errors in the code shown.

Comment: edit* the good url is ?paramID=10&paramToken=FGSDFSFSD but when the "&" is replaced i lost the half of the name of variable

Comment: Something in your app is erroneously translating &para to the pilcrow character.  If you can't find what is doing it, simply rename `paramToken` to `token` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is used to escape special character in html. So you can't just simply use it.

<s>Use [`WebUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx) class to encode the param before injecting it into your message body :</s>

```
message.body = "<html><body>" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(paramMessage) + "</body></html>";
```

EDIT: you need to encode your paramMessage from higher up in the call chain.

The anchor `<a>` part need to be constructed like :

```
string.Format("<a href='...?Confirmation?paramID={0}&paramToken={1}'>",
    WebUtility.HtmlEncode(paramID), 
    WebUtility.HtmlEncode(paramToken))
```

Comment: I have already try System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode but i will try ur WebUtility

Comment: Is not working, the controller dont detect parameter and both of it is not... 

  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Confirmation(string paramID, string paramToken)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. After looking at the content of `paramMessage` my previous answer was not correct.

Comment: It should be obvious to you. Just substitute `id` and `token` for `paramID` and `paramToken` xP

Comment: The `&` inside the `href` attribute must be encoded as `&amp;`. You should `HtmlEncode` _the whole_ `href` attribute before
before calling `sendMail`.

Answer (score -1):

try using "%26" instead of the "&"